# Visual Studio 2013 - C++ Errors

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, compiler-errors, poco

Some strange things happen. When I compile my program in Dev-C++ it gives me no errors and compiles clean. When I put it in Visual Studio I got a LOT of errors:

```
Error   1   error C2371: 'MailRecipient' : redefinition; different basic types
Error   2   error C3861: 'GetModuleFileName': identifier not found  
Error   3   error C2664: 'HRESULT SHGetFolderPathW(HWND,int,HANDLE,DWORD,LPWSTR)' : cannot convert argument 5 from 'char [260]' to 'LPWSTR'
Error   4   error C3861: 'CopyFile': identifier not found
Error   5   error C2664: 'BOOL SetFileAttributesW(LPCWSTR,DWORD)' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'char [512]' to 'LPCWSTR'
Error   6   error C2664: 'HRESULT SHGetFolderPathW(HWND,int,HANDLE,DWORD,LPWSTR)' : cannot convert argument 5 from 'char [260]' to 'LPWSTR'
Error   7   error C2664: 'BOOL SetFileAttributesW(LPCWSTR,DWORD)' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'char []' to 'LPCWSTR'
Error   8   error C2664: 'LSTATUS RegOpenKeyExW(HKEY,LPCWSTR,DWORD,REGSAM,PHKEY)' : cannot convert argument 2 from 'const char [46]' to 'LPCWSTR'
Error   9   error C2664: 'HRESULT SHGetFolderPathW(HWND,int,HANDLE,DWORD,LPWSTR)' : cannot convert argument 5 from 'char [260]' to 'LPWSTR'
Error   10  error C2664: 'LSTATUS RegSetValueExW(HKEY,LPCWSTR,DWORD,DWORD,const BYTE *,DWORD)' : cannot convert argument 2 from 'const char [9]' to 'LPCWSTR'
```

It all works on Dev-C++ tho. I need to compile it in VS because I want to add something from the POCO library, which, ironically, doesn't compile in Dev-C++... Any help?

Comment: Without seeing the code that causes those errors, can't really tell. But at least sounds like you have a problem with your character types and how the code is set to compile (Unicode vs. Multi-byte, etc.)

Comment: @crashmstr I'm not good with compilers knowledge so... Any idea how  can I bypass these errors without actually changing the code?

Comment: @user3478487 To be frank, that is a stupid idea. A compiler error means the code is not valid, why would you want to bypass it?

Comment: Instead of starting with VS, why don´t you try to get POCO working first? Is probably easier. It works on GCC/MinGW (and that is your former compiler, probably, but not DevCPP)

Comment: @Cyber I meant 'get rid of them'. I don't get those errors in Dev-c++. The POCO works, but only in VS... I tried to add the lib and includes folders to the Compiler Includes in Dev (like I did in VS) but it gives me errors, for example in ASCII.h

Answer (score 2):

A Visual Studio project defines **`UNICODE`** by default.

You can either turn off Unicode in the project settings, or rework your program to use `wchar_t` based strings (e.g. `L"Blah"` instead of `"Blah"`).

Or, you can `#undef UNICODE` before including `<windows.h>`, every place.

Comment: I did it and it got rid of 3 errors. Still 7 remaining :(

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be some issues about #include statements in your Project. You need to figure out why MailRecipient gets redefined. You will probably have to adjust some of the project settings in Visual Studio. 
Also, as the first answer suggests Visual Studio uses UNICODE by default, which causes it to call the wide string versions of Windows API functions. You can use the std::widen function to convert your strings just for Windows API calls. For more information on this topic see [utf8everywhere.org](http://utf8everywhere.org#how).

Comment: I rearranged my    #includes     and added POCO ones. I only get 2 errors for CopyFile and GetModuleFileName:     identifier not found.     Any idea?

Comment: Added <stdio.h> and it works. Nevermind :) Thank you all for help!